# $365(x)^{364}-365(x)^{365}+x^{365}=0.9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I can't seem to solve this, I tried using multiple software but it says it doesn't support this kind of equation: $$365(x)^{364}-365(x)^{365}+x^{365}=0.9$$

Context:
Hey! I was having fun with tricked coin flip probability and I came up with that equation at a certain point. If you replace $365$ for $n$ (the exponent $364$ would be $n-1$), and consider it as the number of coin flips, and $p$ as the probability that the favored side of the coin comes up, then $0.9$ (or whatever number, say $y$) is the probability that $A$ happens strictly more than $B$, that the favored side happens strictly more than the unfavored. So: Given that the favored side is greater than the unfavored $90\%$ of the time after $365$ throws, what is the probability of the favored side happening every throw?

The equation I came up with would be formally written:
$np^{n-1}-np^{n}+p^{n}=y$

Comment: You won't solve it algebraically.  $x$ will be rather close to $1$-note that $1$ is almost a solution.  Some sort of numeric method will converge quickly if it doesn't blow up.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives all $365$ roots.  But why oh why are you asking *this* question?!

Comment: What is the difference between $(x)^{365}$ and $x^{365}$?

Comment: Hey! I was having fun with tricked coin flip probability and I came up with that equation at a certain point. If you replace 365 for n (the exponent 364 would be n-1), and consider it as the number of coin flips, and p as the probability that the favored side of the coin comes up, then 0.9 (or whatever number, say y) is the probability that A happens strictly more than B, that the favored side happens strictly more than the unfavored. So: Given that the favored side is greater than the unfavored 90% of the time after 365 throws, what is the probability of the favored side happening every throw

Comment: What $(x)^n$ denotes?

Comment: @Kernos Lovely! Please add that paragraph to your post : it counts as context, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). Placing context in your post will help others tackle your question. Some may suggest probabilistic approximations, given your problem origin is probabilistic.

Comment: Thank you very much @SarveshRavichandranIyer, i added the context to the problem, the equation probably already exists but I'm a newbie at this so I really don't know haha.

Comment: @Kernos Thank you so much and $+1$, I hope someone can answer your question well.

Comment: @jjagmath it denotes "the probability that A happens n times in a row" x being the probability of A happening once

Comment: I tried it on WolframAlpha and got $x\approx 0.999$ as the only real solution that was in the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: You can simplify the equation into $0.9=365y-364 y^\frac{365}{364},x=y^\frac1{364}$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork added info to the original question for context!

Answer (score 3):

As

$$
(365-364x)x^{364}=0.9
$$

defining

$$
f(x) = \ln(365-364x)+364\ln x-\ln 0.9
$$

and calling $\phi(x) = x -\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ the iterative process

$$
x_{k+1} = \phi(x_k)
$$

converges quickly to the solution, giving an initial guess $x_0 \in(0,1)$